# Efficient way to handle large Sentinel - 2 imagery dataset

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, sentinel-2

I need to automatically crop large number of polygons (~200K in a geojson file) from Sentinel-2 images varies both in extent (~30 tiles) and time (from May till August, say it's about 30 images) so if you do the math 200K x 30 x 30 = 180M crops.

Currently I am using GEE code editor for this task but since it has a limit ~3K tasks I first use it to download to **whole complete tiles dataset** (extent and time) to Google Drive and from there to my PC (which gives about 1000 tasks),then I crop each polygon from each tile to get the final dataset.

Obviously, this is very inefficient in terms of bandwidth and storage since I only need ~1% percent of each tile.

Is there any other, efficient, way to download just the data that I need ?
I am not limited to GEE and can use other frameworks.

Comment: https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26